# how can i improve the response time of this Jersey REST Web service call?

Tags: java

I have got a simple Jersey REST Webservice which will read the rss mix url and display the latest news to the website .

But the issue i am facing is that the response is being very slow sometimes and i am getting timeout many times (Ajax call)

will the cache help ??

```
@Path("/latestnews")
public class RssReader {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        JSONArray latestnews = new JSONArray();
        try {
            String url = "http://www.rssmix.com/u/8159030/rss.xml";
            URL feedUrl = new URL(url);
            SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
            SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(feedUrl));
            for (SyndEntry entry : (List<SyndEntry>) feed.getEntries()) {
                JSONObject jsonobj_latestnews = new JSONObject();
                String title = entry.getTitle();
                String link = entry.getLink();
                String pub_date = entry.getPublishedDate().toString();
                jsonobj_latestnews.put("title", title).put("link", link).put("pub_date", pub_date);
                latestnews.put(jsonobj_latestnews);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "jsonCallback(" + latestnews.toString() + ")";
    }
}
```

Could you please let me know how can i improve the response time of the above ajax call ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cache the response from rssmix. And only request updates after a couple of minutes and request only the updates rather than the whole feed (some feed will have this feature). You can even use the HTTP caching capabilities if you use an HTTP client rather than calling the endpoint manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot , could you please tell me how to cache the response from rssmix ??